# Anylogic - Use one resource multiple times at the same time

Tags: service, resources, anylogic

I have a set of surgeons and hospitals. Surgeons perform surgeries in hospitals with which they are affiliated (not every available hospital). Therefore, I have defined two sources: surgeons and hospitals and managed this network through "Resource choice condition". Now, the problem I'm facing is that each hospital can perform multiple surgeries simultaneously in a day. In other words, a hospital can work with multiple surgeons at the same time. But in the code I have written, a hospital remains occupied until a surgery is completed, and it cannot be seized for the next surgery at the same time. I would appreciate it if you could guide me on this.

[the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAuEX.png)